# if $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} f'(x) = L$ then $f'(x_0) = L $

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Let $ f $ be a function that is differentiable on a deleted neighborhood
of $x_0 ∈ R$ and continuous at $x_0$.
Show that if $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} f'(x) = L$ then $f'(x_0) = L $

Comment: Can you use l'Hopital?

Comment: This is none other than the continuity of $ f'(x) $ at point $ x_0 $.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I can use l'Hopital

Comment: @Philip, exactly. So how would you prove that f' is continuum at point $x_0$?

Comment: This is a common dupe.

Comment: @qbert, the assumption says that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, not $f'$. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L'Hopital's rule solution. We want to compute, 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$
which is of indeterminate form $0/0$. So, applying L'Hopital's and noting that the rule only requires differentiability in a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$, we have 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=L
$$
by assumption.

Comment: @ qbert  L'Hopital's rule needs your function to have a limit at the given point. What I did was essentially the proof of L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @GReyes, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, so it has a limit at that point. So using L'Hopital's is great.

Comment: @GReyes yes of course, that is why we get the indeterminate form. Also, yes you did essentially the proof of L'Hopital's rule

Answer (score 2):

@Rizon,

You can apply the MVT on $[x_0,x_0+h]$ with $h>0$ to say that
$$
\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f'(c)
$$
for some $c\in(x_0,x_0+h)$. By taking the limit as $h\to 0^+$, and using the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f'(x)=L$, the definition of (right) derivative and the fact that $c\to x_0$ as $h\to 0^+$, you conclude that
$$
f'_+(x_0)=L
$$
You can do the same for the left derivative, which will also be $L$. Observe that we use the continuity at $x_0$ to be able to apply MVT on both sides.
Hope this helps.